# Writing parsed XML results to CSV

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

I am trying to write to a `CSV` file the results of a query done in an `XML` file, but I can't find a way to properly handle the results in a tabular format.

```py
from lxml.etree import Element, XMLParser, parse
from typing import Any
import csv

p = XMLParser(huge_tree=True)
tree = parse("myfile.xml", parser=p)
root = tree.getroot()

result_values = []
result_values = root.findall("MYTAG")

with open('path/to/csv_file', 'w') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for result_value in result_values:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(result_value.items())
```

With the code above, I get them in this form (with incorrect data and repeated columns as rows):

```py
column1 value
column2 value
column3 value
column1 value
column2 value
column3 value
....
```

What I need is the following, a csv with columns (originally the XML properties) as columns and rows for each of the matched results:

```py
column1 column2  column3 ...
value   value    value
value   value    value
```

How can I export this data to a csv file with the format above, without manually defining column/property names?

Comment: Hi @D.Caan You mentioned a `result of a request made in an XML file`, can you share with us the structure of this XML file.

Comment: The XML file is quite basic and it follows this structure: 

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<export>
<TOPLEVEL>
<MYTAG column1="value" column2="value" />
<MYTAG column1="value" column2="value" />
</TOPLEVEL>

There are lots of properties within "MYTAG".

Comment: The `python-3.x` tag is not quite necessary here as you are not using any Python 3 specific methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your XML mentioned in comments is attribute-centric, consider parsing all attribute dictionaries using list comprehension. Then, write to CSV via [**`DictWriter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```py
with self.input().open() as f: 
    p = XMLParser(huge_tree=True) 
    tree = parse(f, parser=p) 
    root = tree.getroot() 

    # RETURN LIST OF ATTRIBUTE DICTIONARIES
    result_values = [dict(n.attrib) for n in root.findall(".//MYTAG")]

    # RETRIEVE UNIQUE KEYS FOR COLUMN HEADERS
    keys = list(dict.fromkeys([k for dct in result_values for k in dct]))

with self.output().open(mode="w") as f:
    # WRITE TO CSV VIA DICTWRITER
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=keys)
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(result_values)
```

Comment: Getting this error: 

`File /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/csv.py:147, in DictWriter._dict_to_list(self, rowdict)
    145 def _dict_to_list(self, rowdict):
    146     if self.extrasaction == "raise":
--> 147         wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
    148         if wrong_fields:
    149             raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "
    150                              + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) 
I am getting an error, both with the minimal reproducible example as well as with the full dataset and luigi pipeline. Running Python 3.9.

Comment: See slight update, casting `n.attrib` with `dict()`.